# Upload a large file to Amazon S3 from ASP.NET Core Web API Endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-s3, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to upload a file from ASP.NET Core WebAPI endpoint (that uses MultiPart upload) directly to Amazon S3?

All examples of uploading I've manage to find use IFormFile.OpenReadStream() which buffers the entire file to the disk, which is not a good solution for the large files.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming) that describes how to do multipart uploads without buffering.

Comment: Yes, I know how to upload a file to Web API. My question is how to then upload that file to Amazon S3, without buffering

Comment: That wasn't clear from the question. I guess now that you know how to get the stream without buffering on the ASP.NET Core side, you also need to know how to get a stream on the AWS SDK side without buffering? 

Seems like the documentation is here with samples https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/csharp_s3_code_examples.html.

Comment: Yeah, I know about AWS documentation. However using AWS stream uploads requires the Stream to have a set length, which is not true for multipartreader streams, and setting it would require to buffer the stream

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking then. Can you clarify?